# Is not disclosing your address a reason alone to be remanded into prison?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, evidence, governmental-liability, abuse

What do you do if your duty solicitor recommended you to self represent but the judge / court basically ignores the testimony and continue to abuse, exploit and invert language and its meaning/origin backed up by "laws" to put pressure onto someone who is innocent. Why are so many laws designed to intentionally create "criminals"? Those who have the courage to speak out and expose abuse, corruption and crime seem to be more and more considered and labeled a danger or even a terrorist to public safety and health.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be just a rant

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: Godwin's Law

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

Refusing to tell the address **alone** is not a reason to detain somebody. But there are situations where the authorities can demand that a person identifies himself or herself, including such details as the address (or lack of a permanent residency). In such a situation, failure to identify yourself can get you locked up.

---

Also, the tone of your posting seems to question the legitimacy of the UK government and legal system as a whole. That *is* a box you're putting yourself into, and the company you find there is not very pleasant.